# Sinon: Can't install fake timers twice on the same global object

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, sinon

We have been using `useFakeTimers()` (sinon v11.x) in many spec files for quite a long time. Recently, we have updated our sinon to 14.x version, now the tests are failing with below error.

> TypeError: Can't install fake timers twice on the same global object.

We have tried with `createSandbox()` also, didn't help.

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4):

The issue seems like after Sinon 12.x, not restoring the clock in the spec files, injecting it into global scope which throws the aforementioned error.

So the fix is, call `clock.restore()` in `afterAll()` or `afterEach()` based on whether you used `beforeAll()` or `beforeEach()`.

Comment: Or in some case you can advance the clock with clock.tick(time); https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/fake-timers/

Answer (score 2):

So, I encountered this error, for instance, if I had two tests which both used fake timers. You have to call useFakeTimers independently of your sandbox creation.

**Fails miserably because reasons**

```js
/// Somefile 
const superTrialAndErrorSimulator = sinon.createSandbox({
  useFakeTimers: true
});

// Some other file
const superTrialAndErrorSimulatorZool = sinon.createSandbox({
  useFakeTimers: true
});
```

If you set fake timers after setting the sandbox, then reset them, it works. Welcome to the trial and error world of sinon.

**Works miserably because reasons**

```
const ifOnlyThereWereABetterLibrary = sinon.createSandbox();

before(() => {
 ifOnlyThereWereABetterLibrary.useFakeTimers();
});
after(() => {
 ifOnlyThereWereABetterLibrary.clock.restore();
});
// Works.
```

Answer (score 0):

While Sinon's [fake timers documentation page](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v17/fake-timers/) doesn't mention it, there is a [`clock.reset()` method](https://github.com/sinonjs/fake-timers/blob/v11.2.2/README.md#clockreset) mentioned in the GitHub README file. It resets the fake clock to the originally-set value.

FWIW: I first saw this in the tiny [sinon-timers-repeatable](https://github.com/JoshuaKGoldberg/sinon-timers-repeatable/blob/3495f35c6798e6a250140002665411586d10cc81/src/index.ts) library.